# What does the following code segment accomplish?

Tags: c++

I'm struggling to comprehend what this code accomplishes.

```
    position1 = -1;
    position2 = -1;
    for (j = 0; j < 50; j++)
       for (i = 0; i < 50; i++)
          if (arr[i][j] == searchValue) {
            position1 = i;
            position2 = j;
          }
```

Comment: What exactly are you struggling with to comprehend this code? Please be more specific. Looks like a simple search for a specific value in a 2-dimensional array of values. `position1` and `position2` are indexes that are initialized to `-1` and then updated with the indexes where the value is located if found.

Answer (score 0):

We can see from the nested loops (and make an assumption from the variable names `positionx` that we are working through a 2D array.
From the loop limits (50 for both) we can assume it is a 50x50 array.

```
position1 = -1;
position2 = -1;
for (j = 0; j < 50; j++)
   for (i = 0; i < 50; i++)
      ...
```

Next we are looking at the value stored each location in the array and comparing it to a search term `searchValue`, if they are the same then we store the positions where we found that value.

```
if (arr[i][j] == searchValue) {
    position1 = i;
    position2 = j;
}
```

A point to note is that if multiple values meet the search criteria is that we will only store the *last* instance of that value because we don't stop searching or have the ability to store multiple locations.